# Laravel-Backpack: combine hasMany and hasManyThrough to add clauses in list

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-backpack

Here's what I have:

users table

instances table with "project_id" as one of the columns

projects table

instance_user table with "user_id" and "instance_id"

project_user table with "user_id" and "project_id"

When I create users, I want to be able to associate projects and/or instances to users via select2_multiple, adding entries to the pivot tables. Up until here, everything works alright.

Then, when the user logs in, in the instances list, I want them to only see the instances they have associated in the "instance_user" table and also the instances that belong to the projects they have associated in the "project_user" table. So, for example:

users:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Example1 |
| 2 | Example2 |

instances:

| id | name | project_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Instance1 | 1 |
| 2 | Instance2 | 1 |
| 3 | Instance3 | 2 |
| 4 | Instance4 | 2 |
| 5 | Instance5 | 2 |

instance_user:

| instance_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 |

project_user:

| project_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

Here, the user with id=1 would see in the instances list = Instance1, Instance2, Instance4

I tried adding in the InstanceCrudController this:

```
CRUD::addClause('has', 'users');
CRUD::addClause('has', 'instances_through');
```

And these are my User and Instance models:

```
//USER MODEL
    public function instances()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Instance::class);
    }

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class);
    }

//INSTANCE MODEL
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function instances_through()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            User::class,
            ProjectUser::class,
            'project_id',
            'id',
            'id', 
            'user_id' 
        );        
    }
```

But that's clearly not correct, since it doesn't show the expected results, plus I don't think I understand very well how to user hasManyThrough in this case.

Is there any way to do this where one function can return the combined results with the given restrictions? Or any tips on how to approach this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Even my answer get the expected result this is not a good way to get instances when there are millions of records. So you better find a
> different way to achieve this. Most probably try to have db table
> modification where you can get all the instances for a certain user.**

This is the approach you can use based on your table structure.

1. Get Instance id via `instance_user`
2. Get Instance id via `project_user`
3. Merge ids
4. Find instances via merged ids

Sample code. I have tested this and demo project available at [github/nipunTharuksha/Laravel-Backpack-answer](https://github.com/nipunTharuksha/Laravel-Backpack-answer) where I have defined additional relationships also.

```
class InstanceCrudController extends Controller
{
    public function userInstances()
    {
        $user = User::find(1);

        $instance_ids_via_instance_user = (clone $user)->instances()->pluck('instance_id')->toArray(); //Instance id 4
        $instance_ids_via_project_user = Instance::whereIn('project_id', (clone $user)->projects()->pluck('project_id')->toArray())->get()->pluck('id')->toArray(); // Instance is 1,2

        $instance_ids = array_merge($instance_ids_via_instance_user,$instance_ids_via_project_user);

        $instances = Instance::find($instance_ids);

        return response()->json($instances);

    }
}
```

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Prof. Raphaelle Robel DVM",
    "project_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-08-22T17:26:54.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-08-22T17:26:54.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Tianna Glover",
    "project_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-08-22T17:26:54.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-08-22T17:26:54.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Abigale Cummings",
    "project_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2021-08-22T17:26:54.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-08-22T17:26:54.000000Z"
  }
]
```

**Performance**

[image]

Comment: if my answer answer your question hope you can mark this as the answer.Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Your code gave me an idea on how to approach this and it works. I'm sure there are plenty of better and more elegant solutions, but since is a very small project (máx 200 instances and 20-30 projects) I'll go with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing. Would be happy to see different approaches.

```
//InstanceCrudController

    public function get_instance_ids($user_id)
    {
        $user = User::find($user_id);

        $instance_ids_via_instance_user = $user->instances->pluck('id')->toArray(); 
        $instance_ids_via_project_user = Instance::whereIn('project_id', $user->projects->pluck('id')->toArray())->pluck('id')->toArray();

        $instance_ids = array_merge($instance_ids_via_instance_user,$instance_ids_via_project_user);                                                                 

        return $instance_ids;
    }

CRUD::addClause('whereIn', 'id', $this->get_instance_ids(backpack_user()->id));
```